# I want to add a script of the type paperscript in Rails 4 to the head with content_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, paperjs

Using this in my view:

**#show**

```rb
<% content_for :scripts, javascript_include_tag('drawing_I'), type: "text/paperscript", canvas: "drawing_I" %>
```

And this in my main layout:

**application.hmtl.erb**

```rb
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

Then I would like to see a drawing in my html, but what happens is that the paperscript doesn't seem to be picked up, while I did add the paper-full.js library in vender/assets.

The vendor/assets library paper-full library does work, because you can also write these scripts in plain js **and then the drawing does pop up**, but I don't want that, I want paperscripts. It offers a better UX (+ - * / operators for instance, but also not having to define the canvas in the code itself, etc. etc.).

What could be the problem?

I changed the config assets.rb to add: `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )`

and removed `require_tree .` since I won't be needing it.

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken? Does rails render the script tag as intended? Check the HTML source. Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: The error in the browser console is that it can't find element 'Point' meaning that paperscript is not recognized. While if I write my drawing in JavaScript, which is possible, it does draw, hence I think the type is somehow not parsed correctly.

Comment: Did you check the HTML source of the rendered page?

Comment: I'm guessing that you might have to call it like `javascript_include_tag('drawing_I', type: "text/paperscript")` so that you pass the option to `javascript_include_tag` not `content_for`. But I have never used javascript_include_tag with a custom type.

Comment: Thanks that works indeed. Another bug appeared though. When I click the link to the show window I have to reload the page in order for the drawing to show up. Somehow the order of loading isn't right.

Comment: If you have turbolinks enabled you might want to look at https://github.com/rails/turbolinks since the ready event does not fire when turbolinks replaces the page content.

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept your answer if you want. My app is now loading 19 JavaScript scripts and indeed Turbolinks seems to have handeling options that I'd need to dive deeper into in order to solve this problem and make everything run smoothly.

Comment: You can answer your own question. I don't really need the rep

Answer (score 0):

`javascript_include_tag('drawing_I', type: "text/paperscript", canvas: "drawing_I")`

Did the trick. My files are now loaded into the head. Not as effectively as I would like though, because when I load the show page I see no drawings until I reload the page. Very weird, might have got something to do with turbolinks. The page is generally very slow.